# JDBC and MySQL, how to persist java.util.Date to a DATETIME column?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm struggling to understand how to get it to work. I have a prepared statment, and I want to persist a java.util.date. It doesn't work.
I tried to cast it to java.sql.Date, and it still doesn't work.
what's the issue with java date framework, it's really not straight forward.

Comment: How did it not work ? (copy paste any error messages/exceptions you get, if any)

Comment: "*It doesn't work*" is not an error message I have seen with Java or MySQL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) to store a [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) in a `DATETIME` field. If you check the javadocs of both classes (click the above links!), you'll see that the `Timestamp` has a [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp%28long%29) taking the time in millis and that `Date` has a [getter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) returning the time in millis.

Do the math:

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(index, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
// ...
```

You should **not** use [`java.sql.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) as it represents only the date portion, not the time portion. With this, you would end up with `00:00:00` as time in the `DATETIME` field.

For your information only, since `Timestamp` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, you could just upcast it whenever you obtain it from the `ResultSet`.

```
Date date = resultSet.getTimestamp("columnname");
// ...
```

Comment: I read about it over the net, however somesay that the seconds is set to the actual update time of the statment with Timestamp, is it true ?

Comment: @Mellowcandle: a Java timestamp is not the same thing as a MySQL timestamp. The MySQL timestamp data type is, indeed, updated to the current time each time an update to the row is performed (by default). But since you're using datetime, you won't have this behaviour.

Comment: @JBNizet: oh, I see. Mellowcandle is apparently confusing it with MySQL's `now()` function.

Comment: @BalusC: nope. No need for the now() function. A timestamp column is automatically updated. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html : *The TIMESTAMP data type offers automatic initialization and updating.*

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
int dateColumnId = 0; // or whatever the value needs to be.
java.util.Date incomingValue = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
java.sql.Date databaseValue = new java.sql.Date(incomingValue.getTime());   
ps.setDate(dateColumnId, databaseValue);
```

Comment: I find it easier to just convert it to a date/time string (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) and save it, but your way works.

Comment: But it's not a String; it's a Date.  Best to save it that way.

Comment: The database will save it as a Date, it just can take a string in the SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this:

```
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime());
pstmt.setDate(columnIndex,date);
```